# How to add textbox text in array indexes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, textbox

How to add *textbox* text in array indexes?

I have *textbox* with text `"1 22 4 5 6 72"` (separate with space) 
I want to add them in array 
like they should come in this positions,

```
array[0] = 1
array[1] = 22 
array[2] = 4
array[3] = 5
array[4] = 6
array[5] = 72
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to return a new array, like this:

```
array = textbox.Text.Split(' ');
```

Or if you really don't want to create a new array, you can use [`Array.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx):

```
textbox.Text.Split(' ').CopyTo(array, 0);
```

Note, if expect to have multiple spaces between your integers, you should probably use:

```
textbox.Text.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: +1 -Do you need to add `RemoveEmptyEntries` to this too though?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud You don't have to unless you expect there to be multiple spaces, but good point.

Answer (score 0):

You can split by the space and convert each item to int.

```
 int[] myArray = myText.Split(' ').Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string with the Split-Method like:

```
string[] array = tb.Text.Split(new [] {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
```

If you want to sort it by the integer-values or so you can use:

```
array.ToList().Sort((s1,s2) => int.Parse(s1).CompareTo(int.Parse(s2)));
```